# Use of Oracle Advanced Queuing to receive changes of database table rows

Tags: oracle, notifications, queueing

I am confused about Oracle Advanced Queueing. It looks like it is a way to asynchronously send database notification to application layer.
But looking in some details, there is queue to be setup, alongside a table. and there is explicit calls to publish messages that will afterward be pushed to the application layer.

Does this work automatically with table rows modification ?
I want, if a particular table changes (no matter who/how changed), to receive a notification about it in form of a binary object that represents the row changed.

(Note: I know about Oracle Query change notification, CQN, but I am not satisfied with its performance, my goal is then to see if Oracle Advanced Queue can offer similar goal with better speed).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a look at [Oracle Streams Synchronous Capture](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28321/strms_capture.htm#STRMS168).